# Use NodeJS Helper Script in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have written a small helper module in regular NodeJS to be used with NodeJS batch scripts. I've placed this and all the batch scripts in the "private" folder inside my Meteor project.

I'd like to also use the helper module on the server-side of Meteor as well, but I don't know the best way to handle that.

This is my current project structure:

```
client
    ... client files ...
private
    scripts
        helpers.js
        batch_script1.js
server
    ... server files ...
```

So for Meteor to include the "helpers.js" file into the server, it either has to be located in the "server" folder, or imported via a package. Creating a symlink won't work, as multiple developers will be working on this and may have the repository checked out to a different directory location (seeing as how you need an absolute path to create a symlink).

I also don't want to have to duplicate the file and maintain two copies, so what are my options for sharing a helper script between a Meteor app and a NodeJS script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find help on the Meteor forums: https://forums.meteor.com/t/use-nodejs-helper-script-in-meteor/11056/3